# Create textboxes and buttons in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview dynamicaly create from an ODBC datasource.
I want to make something like shopping cart so i want to add a column with textboxes for the quantity and some buttons to add to shopping cart the item in the row.
Is there any example?

Comment: What did you try? What exactly is your problem? 3.7 million results in Dr. Google for _shopping cart example aspx_ ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a EventHandler for RowCreated , this will fire everytime a row is dynamically created
Something similar to this:

```
void gridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    TableCell actionsCell = new TableCell();
    //put code here to add to actionsCell


    // you might have to modify this to specify where in the row to insert
    row.Cells.Add(actionsCell);

}
```

Then put your button or text or whatever you want in this dynamically created cell in the row

Comment: Is there a reason you're removing and then adding back the cell?  Is it just to demonstrate "doing something" with a cell?

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio Open right now to test this  , but I'll give you a better example.

Comment: I want to add a textbox in a column and and a button in another one.
How will be the code?

Comment: Can you be more specific (providing code) on how to add a textbox and a button please?

Comment: I showed example to dynamically add a Cell in a new column to each row as it is created , you may have to Google 'dynamically add textbox control' , then put that text box in the new Cell , then you'll have to Google 'dynamically add button' and add that to another new cell -  you may have a lot more trouble handeling the click events of these new buttons that are dynamically created -  your going to have to do some more research